# How to configure HAProxy with Certbot/letsencrypt

Tags: haproxy, lets-encrypt

I have one domain with several sub-domains. All of them point to my VPS. I use docker in swarm mode to run my web services and my (HA)proxy.
I also use Certbot/Let’s Encrypt in standalone to get the certificate for my domain.

Everything seems to be working fine except the HAproxy configuration for certbot.
Here is my HAProxy config:

```
defaults
    mode    http
    log     global
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull
    timeout check   5s
    timeout connect 5s
    timeout client 50s
    timeout client-fin 50s
    timeout server 50s
    timeout tunnel 1h

resolvers docker
    nameserver dns1 127.0.0.11:53
    resolve_retries 3
    timeout resolve 1s
    timeout retry   1s
    hold other      10s
    hold refused    10s
    hold nx         10s
    hold timeout    10s
    hold valid      10s
    hold obsolete   10s

# HTTP(S) frontend
frontend web-in
    bind *:80
    bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/haproxy.pem

    # test URI to see if its a letsencrypt request
    acl letsencrypt-acl path_beg /.well-known/acme-challenge/
    use_backend be-letsencrypt if letsencrypt-acl

    # sub-domains
    acl sub1 hdr(host) -i sub1.mydomain.com
    acl sub2 hdr(host) -i sub2.mydomain.com
    acl sub3 hdr(host) -i sub3.mydomain.com

    # figure out which one to use
    use_backend be-sub1 if sub1
    use_backend be-sub2 if sub2
    use_backend be-sub3 if sub3

    # Default
    default_backend maintenance

# Backend | LE
backend be-letsencrypt
    server letsencrypt dockerhost:8888 check resolvers docker init-addr none

# Sub1
backend be-sub1
    option forwardfor
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https
    redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc }
    server sub1-server webservice1:8080 check resolvers docker init-addr libc,none

# ... Sub2, Sub3 ...

# Default backend
backend maintenance
    balance roundrobin
```

I expect all the following urls:

```
mydomain.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/
sub1.mydomain.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/
sub2.mydomain.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/
sub3.mydomain.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/
```

to resolve to `dockerhost:8888`. But instead I always get `503 Service Unavailable`.

To test the configuration I run `dockercloud/hello-world` on the port `8888`

```
docker run --rm -d -p 8888:80 dockercloud/hello-world
```

I know that `dockerhost:8888` resolution work fine as I can test it with the following configuration:

```
# Sub1
backend be-sub1
    server letsencrypt dockerhost:8888 check resolvers docker init-addr none
```

Meaning that when I hit my syb-domain `sub1.mydomain.com` I end up on the `dockercloud/hello-world` 
"Hello world!" page.

So why path based resolution doesn't work ? Am I missing something ?

```
acl letsencrypt-acl path_beg /.well-known/acme-challenge/
use_backend be-letsencrypt if letsencrypt-acl
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar issue.

My verification failed with the same 503 error you describe. As I was wondering why that is since I saw the OpenPort of the certbot dockerimage on my machine and the redirects in the HAproxy logs -> I found out that since I was using HAproxy also in an docker Image and the backend server config was connecting to 127.0.0.1 within the HAproxy docker image which of corse cant work as the Port of the certbot was in another docker image I changed the server backend config to the IP address of the Host on which the docker image was running all worked well.

Maybe it helps someone ;) cheers